# Select by foreign language values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

An SQL Server database, I have Table1 like

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | արքայանարինջ |
| 7 | ազնվամորի |
| 9 | արքայախնձոր |

I need something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name  LIKE 'արքայ%'
```

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name  LIKE N'արքայ%'` work? Note the unicode specifier `N`.

Comment: @Arvo  it's working, I have tried something like collate, Unicode(name), and so on.  thank you

Comment: @Arvo, please add it as answer, so it will be helpful for others in future

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with unicode data (`nvarchar` in SQL Server), you have to use unicode strings in form `N'whatever-non-latin-charcaters here'`. Your query becomes then:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Name LIKE N'արքայ%'
```

Comment: Some upvotes and accepts wouldn't hurt either :)